# GBE (Gigabit Ethernet) Magnetic Coils Connection Order

Tags: pcb-design, connector, ethernet, coil, digital-communications

I am designing a MEZ PCB and I need to connect the GBE coils to the assigned pins of single board computer's MEZ connector. My trouble is I do not want to use any more via for this connections. Hence, I want to connect coils with a different order (just the reverse), i.e.:

- MX0+ to MDI3+
- MX0- to MDI3-
- MX1+ to MDI2+
- MX1- to MDI2-
- MX2+ to MDI1+
- MX2- to MDI1-
- MX3+ to MDI0+
- MX3- to MDI0-

Would this work properly?

I will not use following part of the question for my situation, but for being this question a good reference to others, if I connect pins in more complex orders, i.e.:

- MX0+ to MDI2+
- MX0- to MDI2-
- MX2+ to MDI0+
- MX2- to MDI0-
  and so on..

or

- MX0- to MDI0+
- MX0+ to MDI0-
- MX1- to MDI1+
- MX1+ to MDI1-
  and so on..
  would they work? 
  Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Please state the transformer part number. But discrete gigabit transformers should be identical, so as long as it is not a magjack with integrated magnetics then pinout should not matter.

Comment: I replaced the elder magjack with a newer smd one with integrated magnetics, it is 10GBE and part # is ARJE-1034 . Here is the datasheet https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/3/ARJE-1034-1073961.pdf . Just the MDI0 pins' layout is a little different, but gigabit transformers are seem to be identical in datasheet.

Comment: If you're using a jack with integrated magnetics, then they must be connected 1:1, you can't start swapping things around randomly. Unless the PHY supports some sort of lane reversal configuration option, which is possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answers Dear Justme and @alex.forencich . Kind Regards.